Expo BackgroundFetch is not responsing
I started new expo project today with SDK51, I copy-pasted the example code from the backgroundFetch docs, https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/ in the the App.js of the empty project. I run the project on android and don't get any feedback whatsoever, no logs, no nothing, I put console.log in the function registering the task, and I was able to see the log. But, backgrounding the app has no effect (I tried to put alert, console.warn) I opened the example code in the snack following the link in the docs, run the code, clicked the home screen button, nothing.
How to make it work? what is supposed to happen?
